# How to return last part of directory, whilst still accessing the full directory? Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

My current goal is to display last part of the directory in drop down menu in terms of text and still open up the image through full directory.

My current drop down menu only shows full length of directory and works perfectly fine. But I do know how to show last part of the directory by using `os.path.basename`. Unfortunately that just displays the last string of directory, but when I click open, it tries to open last part of the directory instead of the full directory.

**Here is the code:**

```
self.tkvar = StringVar()

# Directory
self.directory = "C:/Users/Eduards/Pictures"
self.choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.directory, "*.jpg"))

# Images
def change_dropdown():
    imgpath = self.tkvar.get()
    img = Image.open(imgpath)
    img = img.resize((529,361))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    label2.image = photo
    label2.configure(image=photo)
    self.CaptureScreen['state'] = 'normal'



#widgets
self.msg1 = Label(main, text = "Choose here")
self.msg1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
self.popupMenu = OptionMenu(main, self.tkvar, *self.choices)
self.popupMenu.grid(row=1, column=0)
self.display_label = label2 = Label(main, image=None)
self.display_label.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan = 500)
self.open_button = Button(main, text="Open", command=change_dropdown)
self.open_button.grid(row=502, column=0)
```

**Here is the output:**

[image]

How can I get the directory only to display the last part of the directory. As an example, from the the above image highlighted in blue only to show `Minions.jpg` or just `Minions`. But in the backround it actually opens up `C:/Users/Eduards/Pictures\Minions.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply, you have to alter the code that does the opening.  The current code merely `get`s the label on which the user clicked and opens that string (file name).  You need to alter your code so that the displayed label is as you want it, but the `open` part of the code pre-pends `self.directory` to that file name.

You've omitted much of the supporting code, but I *think* what you need is

```
img = Image.open('\\'.join(self.directory, imgpath))
```

Comment: what do you mean by pre-pends? sorry I am kinda confused.

Comment: It's the opposite of "append": you need to concatenate `self.directory` in front of `imgpath`, with the separator in between.

Comment: got it working now, thanks for your help.. But i had to change the self.choices to `listdir()`